# Processing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: loops, switch-statement, processing

I'm writing some code for an interactive graphic I'm making which has three states. I used a switch statement to move between the states which showcase an array of images. I uploaded all the images and yet when I call the one state which has an array of 8 images that I uploaded get an error message: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 8`

I can't seem to get rid of it even though I have the correct number of images loaded into my sketch.

Below is my code and I am working on a Macbook Pro OSX using Processing 2.0b7

```
PImage[] teams;
int n = 24;
PImage[] teams2;
int m = 16;
PImage [] quarterFinalWinners;
int o = 7;
PImage bg;
float damping = 0.1;
PFont font;
String[] positions, prevPositions;
float x;
float y;

int afconState = 3;

/**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**/

public void setup() {
  size(600, 1600);
   bg = loadImage("football-pitch-hi.png");

  positions = new String[]{"18", "26", "32", "45", "58", "56", "59", "61", "66", "69", "71", "85", "98", "100", "116", "133"};
  prevPositions = new String[]{"14", "19", "25", "30", "34", "45", "52", "69", "71", "72", "87", "84", "89", "105", "107", "110"};
  int a = 16;

  font = loadFont("Calibri-Bold-48.vlw");
  textFont(font);

  frame.setResizable(true);

  teams = new PImage[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
      teams[i] = loadImage(i + ".png");
    }

  teams2 = new PImage[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < teams2.length; i++) {
      teams2[i] = loadImage(i + ".gif");
    }

   quarterFinalWinners = new PImage[o];
    for (int o = 0; o < quarterFinalWinners.length; o++); {
   quarterFinalWinners[o] = loadImage(o + "_.png");
   }
}

/**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**/

void draw() {
  background(#000000);
  if ((x < width) && (y < height)) {
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++);
    }


  }

/**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**/

public void keyPressed() {
  noLoop();

  switch(afconState) {
  case 1:
   afconState = 1;
   background(#000000);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  image(teams[i], 150, 60*i);
  }
  }

  if ((key == 's') || (key == 'S')) {

    afconState = 2;
    background(#000000);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  image(teams2[i], 150, 60*i);
  }
  }

  else if ((key == 'q') || (key == 'Q')) {
    afconState = 3;
    background(#000000);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  image(quarterFinalWinners[i], 150, 60*i);
  }
  }
  break;

/**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**/    
    case 2:
    if((key == 's') || (key == 'S')) {

    afconState = 2;
  background(#000000);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  image(teams2[i], 150, 60*i);
  }
  }

  else if ((key == 'q') || (key == 'Q')) {
    afconState = 3;
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  image(quarterFinalWinners[i], 150, 60*i);
  }
  }

  break;

  case 3:
  background(#000000);
  if ((key == 'q') || (key == 'Q')) {
    afconState = 3;
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  image(quarterFinalWinners[i], 150, 60*i);
  }
  }

  else if((key == 's') || (key == 'S')) {

    afconState = 2;
  background(#000000);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  image(teams2[i], 150, 60*i);
  }
  }

  break;

  default:
  afconState = 1;
   background(#000000);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  image(teams[i], 150, 60*i);
  }  

  if ((key == 's') || (key == 'S')) {
    afconState = 2;
  // modify the positions list
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  image(teams2[i], 150, 60*i);
  }
  }

  else if ((key == 'q') || (key == 'Q')) {
    afconState = 3;
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  image(quarterFinalWinners[i], 150, 60*i);
  }
  }

  }
  redraw();
}

void mousePressed () {
      // revert to previous array. We can only do this once.
  // if someone pressed the key seven times, we can't revert
  // seven times, because the code only has one history state
  // that is updated every time a key is pressed
  // redraw now that our state has changed

  redraw();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most languages index from 0 (ie. 8 items will be indexed 0 through 7) - It looks like you are trying to reference an array item with index 8 which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: Not sure then - looks like you are using a bad array index somewhere though.